# Tikzpicture shifts subfigure environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, subcaption

I would like an axis drawn with Ti*k*Z in the corner of the image grid to see the increase in variables clearly. The MWE below results in Figure 1. I have tried putting a `\linebreak` in between `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\foreach \a` which results in Figure 2. Ideally, I'm looking to get something like Figure 3 but without the white background on the `tikzpicture` i.e. axis very close to the first figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\(\sigma_{\theta}\)};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) node[below]{\(\sigma_{\phi}\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a in {1,...,2} {
        \foreach \b in {1,...,5} {
            \begin{subfigure}{.185\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
                \caption{\((\a,\b)\)}
            \end{subfigure}
        }
        \linebreak
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### Figure 1

[image: Problem]

#### Figure 2

[image: Current]

#### Figure 3

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if the following is what you're looking for :)

You can tweak the `\vspace{}` and `\hspace{}` to move the axes where you prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \hspace{-1cm}   %shifts the tikzpicture to the left 1cm
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\(\sigma_{\theta}\)};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) node[below]{\(\sigma_{\phi}\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{-0.5cm}  %pulls the following pictures up half a cm
    \begin{center}   % Only centers the pictures, not the axes
        \foreach \a in {1,...,2} {
            \foreach \b in {1,...,5} {
                \begin{subfigure}{.185\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
                    \caption{\((\a,\b)\)}
                \end{subfigure}
            }
            \linebreak
        }
    \end{center}    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

produces:

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\savestack\myaxes{\raisebox{-23pt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\(\sigma_{\theta}\)};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) node[below]{\(\sigma_{\phi}\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
    \foreach \a in {1,...,2} {
        \foreach \b in {1,...,5} {
            \begin{subfigure}{.185\textwidth}
               \ifnum\a=1\relax
                 \ifnum\b=1\relax
                   \stackinset{l}{-15pt}{t}{}{\smash{\myaxes}}{%
                     \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
                   }
                 \else
                   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
                 \fi
               \else
                 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
               \fi
                \caption{\((\a,\b)\)}
            \end{subfigure}
        }
        \linebreak
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The following alternate has less coding, but takes more execution, as it performs a `\stackinset` on each figure.  However, the inset is zeroed out after the first use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\savestack\myaxes{\raisebox{-23pt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\(\sigma_{\theta}\)};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) node[below]{\(\sigma_{\phi}\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
    \foreach \a in {1,...,2} {
        \foreach \b in {1,...,5} {
            \begin{subfigure}{.185\textwidth}
               \stackinset{l}{-15pt}{t}{}{\smash{\myaxes}}{%
                 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
               }
               \global\let\myaxes\relax
               \caption{\((\a,\b)\)}
            \end{subfigure}
        }
        \linebreak
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This third alternative zeroes out the meaning of `\stackinset` after the first use, and restores it after the figure.  Thus, it is more efficient in execution than the prior alternative, and still takes less coding than the originally provided solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\let\svstackinset\stackinset
\newcommand\zerostackinset{\gdef\stackinset##1##2##3##4##5##6{##6}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\savestack\myaxes{\raisebox{-23pt}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{\(\sigma_{\theta}\)};
        \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) node[below]{\(\sigma_{\phi}\)};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}}
    \foreach \a in {1,...,2} {
        \foreach \b in {1,...,5} {
            \begin{subfigure}{.185\textwidth}
               \stackinset{l}{-15pt}{t}{}{\smash{\myaxes}}{%
                 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}%
               }
               \zerostackinset
               \caption{\((\a,\b)\)}
            \end{subfigure}
        }
        \linebreak
    }
\end{figure}
\let\stackinset\svstackinset
\end{document}
```